# Web2py Error: <type 'exceptions.IndexError'> list index out of range

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying a web2py application [here](https://github.com/mdipierro/web2py-appliances/blob/master/SurveyAppFlourish/controllers/survey.py) and I am getting error message. I tried multiple solutions on StackOverFlow and other web resources but couldn't make it work. I know it is problem with list but little point to right direction would be great help. However I tried few solutions and nothing worked for me.

**CODE:**

```
def __edit_survey():
    surveys=db(db.survey.code_edit==request.args[0]).select()
    if not surveys:
        session.flash='survey not found'
        redirect(URL('index'))
    return surveys[0]

def __take_survey():
    surveys=db(db.survey.code_take==request.args[0]).select()
    if not surveys:
        session.flash='survey not found'
        redirect(URL('index'))
    return surveys[0]
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error ticket for "SurveyAppFlourish"
Ticket ID
127.0.0.1.2017-09-23.04-40-15.58fadb34-fbc0-4064-b9e1-ecc67362eafa
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'> list index out of range
Version
web2py™
Version 2.15.3-stable+timestamp.2017.08.07.12.51.45
Python
Python 2.7.12: C:\Python27\python.exe (prefix: C:\Python27)
Traceback
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.
11.
12.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mudassar\PycharmProjects\web2pydemoproject\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "C:/Users/Mudassar/PycharmProjects/web2pydemoproject/web2py/applications/SurveyAppFlourish/controllers/survey.py", line 299, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mudassar\PycharmProjects\web2pydemoproject\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 409, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "C:/Users/Mudassar/PycharmProjects/web2pydemoproject/web2py/applications/SurveyAppFlourish/controllers/survey.py", line 88, in take
    survey=__take_survey()
  File "C:/Users/Mudassar/PycharmProjects/web2pydemoproject/web2py/applications/SurveyAppFlourish/controllers/survey.py", line 45, in __take_survey
    surveys=db(db.survey.code_take==request.args[0]).select()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Error is at `surveys=db(db.survey.code_edit==request.args[0]).select()`

Comment: `request.args` is an empty list or empty string. You cannot get the 0th index of something empty. I suggest checking the existence of request.args first before trying to index it.

Answer (score 0):

In a URL of the form `/app/controller/function/a/b/c`, the parts of the path after `function` (i.e., `a`, `b`, and `c` in this case) are stored as a list in `request.args`. If `request.args[0]` is throwing an `IndexError`, that indicates there are no URL args in the requested URL.

`request.args` is not a standard Python list but an object of class `gluon.storage.List`. It is callable and takes some additional arguments to handle special cases. For example, you can specify a default when there are no URL args:

```
db(db.survey.code_edit == request.args(0, default=my_default)).select()
```

If you simply want a value of `None` when the item does not exist, you do not have to explicitly specify a default:

```
db(db.survey.code_edit == request.args(0)).select()
```

Above, `request.args(0)` will return `None` rather than raise an `IndexError`.

As an alternative, you can specify a redirect URL when the item is missing:

```
db(db.survey.code_edit == request.args(0, otherwise=URL('index')).select()
```

If there is no `request.args[0]`, the above will redirect to the `index` URL. The `otherwise` argument can also be a function (so, for example, you could use it to set `response.flash` and then do a redirect).